# Npm package dependencies not install

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, dependencies

I created npm package from my forked repository: https://github.com/pwalczak83/angular2-datatable

I change only **name** and **version** in package.json, when i install: **npm i -S angular2-datatable-custom** 
i got packet install but there is NO lib directory

However when I install version from which I fork: https://github.com/mariuszfoltak/angular2-datatable
the lib directory after: **npm i -S angular2-datatable** is created

Help me guys plz because without this lib directory my package not working

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your package.json:

```
"angular2-datatable": "https://github.com/pwalczak83/angular2-datatable/tarball/master",
```

This is a way of pointing to your fork and not the original repository.

Check [this link](https://coderwall.com/p/q_gh-w/fork-and-patch-npm-moduels-hosted-on-github) for more details!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your dependencies in your package.json. Then run `npm install`

```
"@angular/common": "^2.4.10",
"@angular/core": "^2.4.10",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.10",
"angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0"
```

It works for me.